# Printer Pagesize at runtime

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have searched and found the answer but it doesn't change the pagesize:

```
Dim xSize As New PaperSize("Custom Paper Size", 62, 100)
Dim xPS As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
prndoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = xSize
```

Where `prndoc` is the printer with associated properties.

The program compiles and runs but still prints the label at 62, 29.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you edited your question to include a link to where you found the previous answer, perhaps the context would help us.

Comment: you must check the paper size at printer settings too.. may be its overriding your paper setting..